# Full Calendar/Angular - Handle date cell content when rendering

Tags: css, angular, typescript, calendar

I'm using the full-calendar component for Angular and I want to customize the content of each date cell according to different conditions. For example if the date is invalid (I have a function that validates the date), I want to change the date's cell background color. Otherwise, if its valid I want to add a plus button inside to add events. Besides that I want to add custom animations and hover effects.

How can I take control of the date is being render ?

I manage to change the background color with `dayCellDidMount` hook:

```
dayCellDidMount: (arg) => {
      if(!this.dateIsValid(arg.date, arg.isPast)){
        arg.el.style.backgroundColor = "#eeeeee";
      }
},
```

I don't think that's the best way to do it and I still can't manage to add the plus button inside the cell.

Can someone achieve this or something similar? Your help would be appreciated, thanks.
If you know another calendar to integrate with Angular that has this features I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: On thing you could do would be to change className instead of a specific css property for complex styling that can be better

Comment: @JSmith I tried that but this override the classes that are already set in the <td> like "fc-day" "fc-future" etc. Also I have problems with styling when changing the month view.

Comment: could you make a stackblitz to reproduce the problem and add it to your post please? also perhaps if you set the propertys to `!important`you won't have this override problem. Best.

Comment: @JSmith the `!important` dont modify anything because the main problem is that for example the original <td> has the following classes `fc-daygrid-day fc-day fc-day-wed fc-day-future`. After I validate the date if i do `arg.el.className = "day-disabled";` the <td> will only have the `day-disabled` class and lose the others. I want to add that class and kept the others. Besides that, i cant reproduce it exactly with stackblitz because I manage data from databases. Basically if I use className instead of style (apart from previous problems ) the style doesn't show properly when changing months.

Comment: to avoid deleting all other classes use render2 an use `addClass`. this will do something like `this.renderer.addClass(element, 'my-class-name');`. also if you have css problem this may come from the fact that your adding you class to the wrng level that's only a supposition but baically if it works with element.style this should work with pure css. For the database problem just use a raw json object as I suppose you are retrieving json from your backend. Instead of doing `subscribe` just add a variable with dummy data. Best

Comment: @JSmith thats a better approach but still having styling problems. I figure where the problem is. When I initially render the calendar my class is applied but when I change the view to another month the original classes override my custom class on that date cell. It only happens on days that are showed on both months. For example in the view of October month I can still see days 28, 29 and 30 of September because October starts on a Thursday. So when I go to september and then back to october that row doesn't have my custom class. I would try to make a stackblitz

Comment: It seems that the `dayCellDidMount` hook executes only once on initial rendering.

Comment: depends where you placed it and of your change detection strategy